# What is the "Memory SPD Information" in Memtest86+ and why is it different from what I expect?

Tags: memory, memtest86+

I have [this 32GB memory kit](https://www.corsair.com/us/en/p/memory/cmk32gx5m2b5600c36/vengeancea-32gb-2x16gb-ddr5-dram-5600mhz-c36-memory-kit-a-black-cmk32gx5m2b5600c36) that I just ran against Memtest86+. See screenshot here
[image: https://imgur.com/a/oUZ191A]

The part that says `IMC: DDR5-5600 / CAS 36-36-36-76` is accurate. But why does the "Memory SPD Information" part say `2GB DDR5-4800` (rather than `16GB DDR5-5600` as I would expect)?

I understand that my RAM is working as intended, the O/S reports the correct quantity and clock speed. I guess I'm just trying to understand what that "Memory SPD Information" section is telling me.

Possibly related, this is XMP memory that I used the ASUS BIOS "AI Tweaker" set to "XMP 1" which automatically sets all the correct clock speeds and timings somehow. This was my first time using that tool.

Comment: You should post this in the [Memtest86+ forum](https://github.com/memtest86plus/memtest86plus/issues). Memtest86+ is being upgraded continuously, but there might be room for further improvement.

Comment: SPD module identification is entirely based on software your screenshot also indicates the module could it be identified. Software must be updated to properly identify and detect your memory. Report the defect to the developer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The SPD profiles stored in the memory module chip are very conservative "standard" profiles that are guaranteed to work on practically any system that supports DDR5 memory.

XMP profiles are an *extension* to the SPD system, not necessarily present in all memory sticks or enabled by default in the system.

That means that programs that read the true SPD information from your stick is going to get the DDR-4800 settings. It has to actually go slightly beyond the "standard" SPD system because [XMP data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_presence_detect#Intel_Extreme_Memory_Profile_(XMP)) is not necessarily in the same format as [SPD data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_presence_detect#DDR3_SDRAM). If you are reading only standard SPD data then XMP data may not give sensible results with the same assumptions.

To know what memory settings are in use you should consult the actual integrated memory controller in your CPU, indicated by the `IMC:` line, to find out what settings it has selected. Those settings may well match up with what is dictated by either the SPD or XMP profiles, but may also diverge depending on what the motherboard or processor itself has decided are better settings.

More aggressive "XMP Tweaker" settings on your motherboard may find faster or better settings than specified by the memory, at the cost of potentially taking slightly longer to "train" the memory at boot up.

I also expect the `2GB DDR5-4800` is referencing the *per chip* size and speed settings. The SPD information lists `Total SDRAM capacity *per die* in megabits` and the die count is listed later in the SPD block. A casual glance at the SPD settings will not list the full stick capacity without some actual math. (This is based on what is openly available about the DDR3 standard as I do not have access to the [JEDEC DDR5 SERIAL PRESENCE DETECT (SPD) CONTENTS](https://www.jedec.org/standards-documents/docs/jesd400-5b) specifications sheet, but the information makes sense to extrapolate to later standards as you need to know number and capacity of devices to use the stick properly).